# Screen Scraping a Fully Rendered Page

Tags: jquery, ruby, iframe, screen-scraping

I'm trying to figure out how to capture a fully rendered page and manipulate it. I've been using Nokogiri, Hpricot, Mechanize, etc., but none can capture a page whose elements are rendered by AJAX or something else after the fact.

An example is Twitter's status page, one of many that I've come across for this project that I'm having trouble with:

http://twitter.com/#!/nytimes/status/42341419062525952

or

http://twitter.com/#!/alleyinsider/status/42337897038364672

If you look at the HTML source, it's mostly javascript that shows up rendered later. Checking it out in Firebug or another console, you see the fully rendered result, but I have no idea how to capture it with the aforementioned tools. Am I missing something?

BTW: Yes, I know there is a Twitter API. But this is more of a theoretical issue as I have hit this in varying degrees on a few other sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...none can capture a page whose elements are rendered by AJAX or something else after the fact.

That is correct. The content you seek doesn't exist in the document when captured, it's inserted as a result of the browser processing the JavaScript, which requests the content via AJAX and inserts it into the page.

So, to get where you want to go, you'll need either a JavaScript interpreter or a browser under your code's control.

The [Watir](http://watir.com/) project is capable of doing that. It's like the next step above Mechanize, except, instead of being Ruby code, it's a browser being told what to do by your Ruby code. So, the browser should be able to load the page, process the JavaScript, which then pulls in the content you're looking for.

There are [variations on Watir](http://watir.com/platforms/) for the different browsers, so you can use IE, Safari, Firefox, etc.

Comment: I'd heard of Watir, but had never checked it out fully. I'll do so now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WebDriver? It loads the whole page up in a browser (real or virtual), you can explore the DOM of the page, and you can pass it javascript commands to execute if you want to modify the page.

Comment: I hadn't heard of it before. I'll definitely check it out though.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the data you're trying to scrape is retrieved via Ajax then, if possible, you're better aiming your sights there.

Outside of that, API's help a lot (as you mentioned). Funnily enough, it looks like that's just how the Twitter website works [like your example](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?include_entities=true&contributor_details=true&id=42341419062525952) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a scraping project myself and have been using Celerity with pretty good success.  Here are a couple resources that should be helpful. The second link specifically addresses Ajax.

Getting Started: [Celerity - Wiki Getting Started](https://github.com/jarib/celerity/wiki/Getting-started)

Ajax Specific: [Celerity - Wiki (Ajax)](https://github.com/jarib/celerity/wiki/Ajax)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are runnign java, you may want to look at *lobo browser* which you can instantiate through your code and and render the page. http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp. I once tried this but later gave up for more simple solution without ajax content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IRobotSoft web scraper and get the UpdatedPage.  Check these demos: http://irobotsoft.com/help/